# How to replace or convert " to \" in a column value in SQL

Tags: sql, json, apache-spark-sql

I want to replace or convert  " to \"  for a column value in SQL , I am working it in pyspark sql

For example : Desc = MEDIUM (8.1"-10.0") LIGHT WEIGHT PAPER PLATE

I want to convert into

```
    Desc = MEDIUM (8.1\"-10.0\") LIGHT WEIGHT PAPER PLATE
```

Struggling from last 2 days to solve it , very much appreciate your help.

Comment: It sounds like an x/y question, why do you want to do this? Are you having trouble somewhere else because the quotes are not escaped?

Comment: Actually , I am writing my target into json file , json file won't accept string in a string . If I place the sting in json like "Desc" : "MEDIUM (8.1\"-10.0\") LIGHT WEIGHT PAPER PLATE" , it will accept else it will consider as new string

Comment: If you are writing to a JSON file, are you using a JSON framework such as JSON.Net to do so? If so it will automatically handle escaping of quotes etc. If you aren't using a JSON framework then unless you have a good reason not to, I'd consider using one.